# Streaming, SIlverlight MediaFramework, Not playing in Device

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, media, http-live-streaming

I am trying to stream video content to a windows phone.
I am using the following code.
"player" is the Silverlight Media Player used here.

```
PlaylistItem item = new PlaylistItem(); 
item.DeliveryMethod =  Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives.DeliveryMethods.AdaptiveStreaming;
item.MediaSource = new Uri("http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/SSWSS720H264/SuperSpeedway_720.ism/Manifest");
item.VideoHeight = strmPlayer.Height;
item.VideoWidth = strmPlayer.Width;
player.Playlist.Add(item);
player.Play();
```

I am able to play it in the emulator but on the Device i dont see anything.
Can anyone correct me where i am going wrong ?

I sometimes get this log in the debug output window.
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bandwidth issue ! MY pc was using a good speed internet connection and so it was able to play the stream.
My device was connected to the WIFI hub, which was out pf range at some points.
When i took my device near the hub, the stream was played.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using latest version of the Silverlight Media Framework as available from Codeplex? Could it be a bug in the implementation you are using and latest version could correct that? Otherwise, it is hard to investigate what could be wrong in the network connectivity on the device versus that on your emulator.

BTW, what device are you using?